# .Net Core DI - multiple instances of the same type

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, .net-core, inversion-of-control

First of all, I saw some topics similar to mine, however I think they don't really answer my issue.

I am creating an application, which, depending on configuration can work in multiple modes. The app is a simple importer/exporter of data from database to files. It can actually transfer data:

- between files and DB
- between DB and another DB

The first case is not problematic, the second one is. My application has classes like:

- `FilesReader`
- `FilesWriter`
- `DbReader`
- `DbWriter`

I think you can see how I can connect them together to read from one source and write to another. Problem appears when I want to use `DbReader` and `DbWriter` at the same time. Since both of them require `IDbClient` in their constructors, I need to have a way to pass to them different instances of it (since `DbReader` will read from Database A and `DbWriter` will write to database B).
In reality, I actually have more classes that need `IDbClient`. For example I have `DbDataCache`, which will need instance of `IDbClient` to connect with Database A, and so on.

There are a few ways that I think of how it could be achieved. However, I don't really like any of them. Here're my ideas:

1. While registering each class to the container, I could register them "manually" - create each `IDbClient`, create each class that depends on it and pass the right instances to them - I don't like it, because I lose the easiness of registration, it becomes quite complicated and there is a lot of `new` keyword use.
2. I could create a `DbClientFactory` and register `IDbClient` instances with some names (like `DatabaseA` and `DatabaseB`) - I don't like it, because the classes that need `IDbClient` will now need to know the name that they should require.
   So, probably `DbReader` would need to have somethink like this in its constructor

```cs
_dbClient = _dbFactory.Get("DatabaseA");
```

while `DbWriter` will have:

```cs
_dbClient = _dbFactory.Get("DatabaseB");
```

What do you think? Maybe there is some other DI container that would be more suitable for my needs than the .Net Core built-in one?

Comment: Make your `IDbClient` generic `IDbClient<T>` and register one for the writer and one for the reader and in the writer request `IDbClient<DbWriter>` and in reader request `IDbClient<DbReader>`. Your factory idea is also in my opinion a valid aproach.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius I don't like the idea of changing my classes just for DI to work. Such DI becomes "intrusive" in my opinion.

Comment: Well it’s as intrusive as needing a separate factory class. Imo the generic is cleaner design. You could also use marker interfaces instead of generic. In any way you need a mechanism to register two instances of the same concrete and then identify them separately.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius The factory class is not intrusive, because it's a seperate class, my IDbClient implementation does not need to change in any way, while changing the interface for generic one is intrusive :) I'll keep on looking for some good solution. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding from your explaination is that; Your solution would be to have new instance of IDbClient served on each request to DI Container. If that's true try to register your service as Transient

```
 services.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>();
```

as per docs

**Transient Lifetime**

If in doubt, make it transient. That’s really what it comes down to. Adding a transient service means that each time the service is requested, a new instance is created.

Comment: Not really. Actually, I have many classes, where some of them should get IDbClient for Database A and some others should get IDbClient for Database B

Answer (score 0):

I would use the same approach that is used for loggers in .NET Core itself. So, instead of registering in DI each separate logger you usually register ILoggerFactory and then inject it in the necessary class and create a logger with `CreateLogger(name)` function.

So, the similar way as with logging you can register in DI some implementations of IDbClientFactory, inject it where it's needed and call something like `dbClientFactory.CreateReader(dbName1)` or `dbClientFactory.CreateWriter(dbName2)` to create actual reader or writers.

Funny thing. About 2 weeks ago we had published a [.NET Core global tool](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Korzh.DbTool/) which does the same tasks: importing and exporting the data from some common formats (JSON, XML) to DB and vice versa. The tool itself and the underlying library are totally open-source and [published on GitHub](https://github.com/kedonec/Korzh.DbUtils). So, feel free to use that code in your own project if you find there something useful.

Comment: Regarding loggers, I actually register logger with "built-in" AddLogging extension methods. I don't inject ILoggerFactory to my services, but rather ILogger<MyService>. This way, the logger is injected automatically, I don't need to create it from factory. Problem with your solution is that my services need to know "dbName1" and "dbName2". I'm thinking after all to actually register services manually, I mean "new" them up and add the "proper" instances to container. So, only the services athat are "single" (do multiple instances require) would end up in a container

Comment: Interesting project. My database is of RTDB type, I see your project is more for SQL DBs. My solution enables 4 modes: DB->files; files->DB; DB->DB; files->files (useful when input is in JSON, but I want CSV for example). Maybe you could consider adding such scenarios, especially DB->DB ;)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the possibility to inject a logger via ILogger<MyService>. Just want to point out that there is another way via ILoggerFactory which allows creating several different loggers depending on some run-time preferences. 
I thought more in terms of our tool where some options (like an input/output data format, or a database type) come as command-line parameters and the program needs to create a particular implementation (like JsonDatasetReader or XmlDatasetReader) on the fly.
Glad that the problem is solved now.

Comment: About the DbTool. Adding an additional database here is a matter of implementing IDbReader and IDbWriter interfaces for it.
The new format (like CSV) can be added by implementing IDatasetExporter (for exporting) and IDatasetImport (for importing). We definitly add the support for CSV format at least for exporting operation.

Comment: As for DB -> DB scenario. It would be also quite easy, I think. There can be a "copy" command which simply takes two connection IDs as arguments.